# Visual C# key detecting anomaly (D character added) while reading RFID card

Tags: c#, .net, barcode, keydown, rfid

I'm developing a program in Visual C# 2015 which should authenticate users through rfid cards. The device I'm using simply emulates a keyboard: let's say I open notepad, then swipe the tag or card near the reader, and I get the serial number + enter, much like most barcode readers work.
Obviously, I don't want the user to see the code, nor make him/her able to type it in a textbox, so the idea is catching the input from "that keyboard" at authentication, using KeyDown event, putting all characters in a buffer variable and then checking it against the database when enter is pressed (that is, the end of the code).

The problem is, say the card is marked as 12345678, this is what I get in notepad or in a textbox. But when I display the buffer, I get "D1D2D3D4D5D6D7D8"; I could simply avoid the problem by adding a D before each character of the database, but I really want to understand why this happens. Is it a matter of coding, or maybe the keydown events are too near to each other? Does anybody have a clue? Thank you

EDIT:

Here's the code:

XAML

```
<Window x:Class="myApp.MainWindow"
    (...)
    KeyDown="OnKeyDownHandler">
```

C#

```
private void OnKeyDownHandler(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!authenticated) {

            if (e.Key != Key.Enter)
            {
                cardReadBuffer += e.Key;
            }
            else
            {
                //this returns every character preceded by a D; doesn't happen
                //if I type some characters on my keyboard and then press enter
                MessageBox.Show(cardReadBuffer);
                cardReadBuffer = "";
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `But when I display the buffer...` That's the code you need to show us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The KeyDown event is just giving you the actual key being pressed, so try using the TextInput event to handle the string part:

```
private void OnKeyDownHandler(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {     
  if (e.Key == Key.Enter) {
    MessageBox.Show(cardReadBuffer);
    cardReadBuffer = "";
    e.Handled = true;
  }
}

private void OnTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e) {
  cardReadBuffer += e.Text;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it works, but I'm still missing (technically speaking) what's the difference between an actual key being pressed on a keyboard and the "key" pressed by the rfid reader which somehow results in a "D1" key being pressed. And still a regular character as text input

Comment: @didrocks66 If you press the number keys on the number pad (assuming your keyboard has them), you get "NumPad1NumPad2NumPad3..." or press Shift-X and you will see "LeftShiftX".  The event is telling you the key that is being pressed, not the "value" that is being transmitted to the TextBox, etc.